# Python: select n of each type from ordered dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a for loop that contains multiple if -conditions. The speed of this function is not critical for my application at the moment but I'd like to learn and have a few tips how to optimize my code to make it run faster. In my loop, I get first 5 A's, 5 B's and first 2 C's of each type `C_1` and `C_2`. The code is working correctly, I get a wanted output but I'd like to make it as efficient as possible as I'm not sure how big amount of data it will be given at some point later. Here's the code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict


odl = [OrderedDict([('id', '1'), ('date', '2022-01-08'), ('time', '15:59:00'), ('type', 'A')]), OrderedDict([('id', '8'), ('date', '2022-01-08'), ('time', '14:59:00'), ('type', 'A')]), OrderedDict([('id', '2'), ('date', '2022-01-09'), ('time', '11:59:00'), ('type', 'A')]),  OrderedDict([('id', '3'), ('date', '2022-01-08'), ('time', '12:59:00'),  ('type', 'B')]), OrderedDict([('id', '9'), ('date', '2022-01-09'), ('time', '17:59:00'),  ('type', 'B')]), OrderedDict([('id', '4'), ('date', '2022-01-09'), ('time', '18:59:00'), ('type', 'B')]),
       OrderedDict([('id', '5'), ('date', '2022-01-08'), ('time', '09:59:00'), ('type', 'C'), ('C_TYPE', 'C_1')]), OrderedDict([('id', '6'), ('date', '2022-01-09'), ('time', '10:59:00'), ('type', 'C'), ('C_TYPE', 'C_2')]), OrderedDict([('id', '7'), ('date', '2022-01-07'), ('time', '16:59:00'),  ('type', 'A')])]

sorted_list = sorted(odl, key=lambda item: (item['date'], item['time']))
sl_list = []
type_a = 0
type_b = 0
type_c_1 = 0
type_c_2 = 0
for s in sorted_list:
    if s['type'] == 'A':
        if type_a < 5:
            sl_list.append(s)
            type_a += 1
    if s['type'] == 'B':
        if type_b < 5:
            sl_list.append(s)
            type_b += 1
    if s['type'] == 'C':
        if s['C_TYPE'] == 'C_1':
            if type_c_1 < 2:
                sl_list.append(s)
                type_c_1 += 1
        if s['C_TYPE'] == 'C_2':
            if type_c_2 < 2:
                sl_list.append(s)
                type_c_2 += 1
```

Example output:

`[OrderedDict([('id', '7'), ('date', '2022-01-07'), ('time', '16:59:00'), ('type', 'A')]), ...]`

Are there some obvious performance issues I could face with bigger amounts of data? I'd appreciate every tip to make this more efficient!

Comment: (With a language having a documentation convention, I think missing documentation a *code smell*. Functions/methods (and their parameter) should have a telling name: telling their reason to exist. Same goes for variables/data members. Guess what I think of code lacking all that.)

Comment: That example output is surprising, given that the program has no commands that might produce output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use a collection rather than spawning lots of similarly named variables**.
Anytime you find yourself creating a bunch of numbered/lettered variables, stop
and figure out a way to put that information in a collection. If your data
is smart, your code can often be simple.

**Applying limits when collecting data by type**. You appear to want to control
the number of dicts of each type that you collect. Rather than weaving those
limits into your algorithm, define a data structure holding the maximums. And
then while collecting the data, use a copy of that collection to keep track of
how many of each type are still available to be selected.

**Start putting your code in functions**. Even for small programs.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

ODL = [...]

MAXES = {
    ('A', None): 5,
    ('B', None): 5,
    ('C', 'C_1'): 2,
    ('C', 'C_2'): 2,
}

def main():
    for d in select_dicts(ODL):
        print(d)

def select_dicts(ods):
    sort_key = lambda od: (od['date'], od['time'])
    type_key = lambda od: (od['type'], od.get('C_TYPE'))
    available = dict(MAXES)
    selected = []
    for od in sorted(ods, key=sort_key):
        k = type_key(od)
        if available[k] > 0:
            selected.append(od)
            available[k] -= 1
    return selected

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```